# Keep mouse pointer within frame/window

Tags: java, swing, mouse

I want to prevent the mouse from being moved out of the window. I've seen it done before on Minecraft, where you have to press esc to release the mouse from the window.

Comment: Very similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543065/how-do-i-lock-the-mouse-inside-a-jframe

Comment: Does minecraft request trust from the user?  (Just curious because of the mention of `Robot`.)

Comment: It's a downloadable jar file, so I assume it has all permissions etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java you can use the Class [Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to position the mouse cursor anywhere on the screen. You could use this to move the mouse position back to the center after each mouse move event.

```
//Moves mouse pointer to given screen coordinates.
void mouseMove(int x, int y)
```

Comment: The mouse still needs to move within the window, so I could use that method but just stop it from going out of bounds. But if the user moves the mouse fast enough, the mouse will leave the screen before it is even detected. Would I just have to disable the mouse from entering, say, a 10px padding around the window?